# How can I create the following arrays

Tags: python, arrays

How could I create arrays for items in a list
something like

```
list = ["a","b","c"]
  for thing in list:
    thing = []
```

Comment: What should the result be? Currently it looks like you want to replace every item in `list` (you should give it another name) with an empty list: `[[], [], []]`.

Comment: id ultimately like, a = [], b = [], c = []

Comment: @user428370: writing the simple assignment statements seems simpler than fooling around with a loop.  What's the point of making this more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean creating global arrays (module level) then you can do this:

```
for thing in list:
    globals()[thing] = []
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the strict response to what you are asking is:

```
for x in lst: 
    locals()[x] = []
```

`locals` may be `globals`, depending on what you want. But it's usually advisable to use a dictionary to hold these values instead (as other have already proposed).

[Edit] another way:

```
locals().update(dict.fromkeys(lst, []))
```

Comment: This example like the one above are the just what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
x = dict ([(name, []) for name in ["a", "b", "c"]])
```

?

or maybe

```
x = [[] for name in ["a", "b", "c"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`[list() for i in items]`

`[list() for i in range(len(items))]`

If you want to wrap the current elements of `items` in lists, you can do

`[[i] for i in items]`

`items` is used for the variable name since `list` is a builtin.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["a","b","c"]
for thing in list:
  exec(thing+"=[]")
```

is this what you want?